# Oracle Bucketing Values

Tags: range, bucket, oracle11gr2

I am trying to write a query to get counts of values in different ranges.

Let us say my table has a column called 'Name' and another column called 'Value' which is numeric.

The 'Value' column can take values from 1 to 100.

Currently I am writing a query like

```
select count(1) from table where value between 1 and 10
union all
select count(1) from table where value between 11 and 80
union all
select count(1) from table where value between 81 and 100.
```

The query gives me the results but seems to perform veeeeeerrrrry SLOW.

Is there a better way to do this ?

Please remember that I cannot partition the table based on the values in the 'Value' column as I have other columns as well.

## Edit

Ok I am going to modify the above query to

```
select count(distinct names) from table where value between 1 and 10
union all
select count(distinct names) from table where value between 11 and 80
union all
select count(distinct names) from table where value between 81 and 100.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first query, assuming you don't care whether you get one row with three columns or three rows with one column, you could do something like

```
SELECT SUM( CASE WHEN value BETWEEN 1 AND 10
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
             END) num_between_1_and_10,
       SUM( CASE WHEN value BETWEEN 11 AND 80
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
             END) num_between_11_and_80,
       SUM( CASE WHEN value BETWEEN 81 AND 100
                 THEN 1
                 ELSE 0
             END) num_between_81_and_100
  FROM table_name
```

That will let you scan the table once rather than scanning it three times.

The second query, in general, returns a different result set.  You can match your second query with a different query

```
SELECT COUNT( DISTINCT( CASE WHEN value BETWEEN 1 AND 10
                             THEN name
                             ELSE null
                         END) ) num_distinct_between_1_and_10,
       COUNT( DISTINCT( CASE WHEN value BETWEEN 11 AND 80
                             THEN name
                             ELSE null
                         END) ) num_distinct_between_11_and_80,
       COUNT( DISTINCT( CASE WHEN value BETWEEN 81 AND 100
                             THEN name
                             ELSE null
                         END) ) num_distinct_between_81_and_100
  FROM table_name
```

Comment: @Anand - Can you explain what is "not good enough" means specifically?  Are the results not quite what you're looking for?  If so, can you give some details about what the query is or is not returning correctly?

Comment: I have modified my query to count distinct

Comment: Posted a second query in my answer for the second query in your question.

Comment: i want the count of the distinct names is there any way i can do that

Comment: @Anand - Sorry, I didn't notice that you had changed the query to select distinct names, not distinct values.  I updated my query to match.

Comment: now that helps thanks a lot !! now that takes me only 3 seconds